# Lost information when status update

Tags: facebook

After trying out setting on relationship status, Facebook accidentally "deleted" all likes and text written from friend from the original Facebook relationship update. This happened for both parties :)

Is there a way to retrieve this information/ retract to original status and keeping text written?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say so, but what you are asking for is clearly not possible. Once it is deleted from your account, you cannot get it back no matter what.

Comment: Do you have any reference to back this up?